# Should we need two servers to run ext js application with node.js at server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs, extjs4

I am new to Node.js , I have downloaded a sample application where server side was written in Node. I am building and running my Ext js application using sencha cmd at localhost:1841.At the same time I am running server.js  in node(Express server) at port 3000. And the application is running successfully with data from serverside.

Can we run ext js application in server running at 3000.I mean can we deploy the ext js appliction in node,So that both the client and serverside will be on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can totally do that. You can think of the extjs application as just more static assets served by node (like css or html pages).

I do the same thing all the time using node, java, and python applications.

Of course, for production you might consider using ngnix or apache to server your static content :).